Streamlit app - make API call only once per day?
I have a Streamlit app I’m working on now that tells me which bands are playing tonight in my city. You can find it at musicinseattle.
To get the information, the app has a module that makes a few calls to a ticketing service API, and another module (still under construction) which will scrape the calendars of some venues that only sell tickets through their own web site, at the door, or through the bands that they book.
Right now, the module that calls the API is run every time the app is accessed, i.e., called once for each user. I’m trying to figure out a way that I can run this API code only once per day, just after midnight, pre-save the information, and then use that with the users throughout the day.
For efficiency, I want to limit the number of times I have to call the API and also not having to use the scraping module when the page is loaded will increase loading times for the users. It also helps me minimize errors, as the API is finicky and I have an algorithm to check for errors and re-call it if there are any, so I'd rather that happen just once per day.
Does anyone have any ideas on how I might achieve this?
To be honest, I'm not sure what to try here.  This is a new problem for me and I'm unsure how to approach it.  If someone could even just point me in the right direction, that would be amazing.
from ticketing_api import get_shows
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
from time import sleep

print("Line 5, Main")

df = pd.read_csv("Seattle_ticketing_venues - Sheet1.csv")

shows_tonight = {
    "venue": [],
    "show": [],
    "date": []
}


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    venue, bands, date = get_shows(row["Venue Name"], row["vID"])
    shows_tonight["venue"].append(venue)
    shows_tonight["show"].append(bands)
    shows_tonight["date"].append(date)
    sleep(0.09)


df_show_data = pd.DataFrame(shows_tonight)

st.title("Who's Playing in Seattle Tonight?")
st.subheader("The quickest way to find out who's playing TONIGHT at our local music venues.")
with st.expander("Welcome to my web app! It's still under development so expect some changes. "
                 "Here's the best way to use it:", expanded=True):
    st.markdown("""
    - This app is meant to be used on a big screen.  If you're on a phone, turn it sideways.
    - If any venues are showing 'No Info,' reload the page, this may be an error because I'm a terrible coder
    - Save this webpage to your phone's home screen so you can access it just like an app!
    
    ---
    
     Share this app with your friends!
    
    """)

st.dataframe(df_show_data, use_container_width=True, hide_index=True)


Soo @st.cache_data(ttl=24 * 3600)? What research did you do? What documentation did you read? So why not create a file with the data and only refresh if the timestamp of the file is older than 24h? What exactly is the issue?
